# Directory Dialog doesn't scroll to the filter path set.

Tags: java, swt

My Directory Dialog code:

```
    Display.getDefault().syncExec(() -> {
        Shell shell = new Shell(Display.getDefault(), SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL);
        shell.setSize(0, 0);
        shell.open();

        DirectoryDialog directoryDialog = new DirectoryDialog(shell, SWT.SHEET);
        directoryDialog.setFilterPath(myPath);
        directoryDialog.setMessage("My Message");
        directoryDialog.setText("My Title"));
        shell.forceActive();
        shell.setActive();
        shell.setImage(Icons.IMAGE_APP_LOGO);

        if (SysInfo.isWin()) {
            shell.setMinimized(true);
            shell.setMinimized(false);
        }
        favoriteParentFolder = directoryDialog.open();
        shell.dispose();
    });
```

My Issue is:

Lets assume myPath = `"C:\\Username\\Desktop\\Z Folder"`

I have "A Folder", "B Folder", ... inside Desktop.

The Directory Dialog View, doesn't show Z Folder as my selection. I am required to scroll down to see.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior with Eclipse RCP 4.5, except that the first (and only the first) DirectoryDialog in the process *does* scroll to the filter path. Might be addressed by this [Eclipse bug asking for a modern directory dialog](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=443250), currently targeted for Eclipse 4.8.

Comment: Works OK on macOS so this may be a problem with the Windows version of the dialog.

Comment: @greg-449 that's the case. Need to address this issue in Windows.